# Modify XML content based on XPath DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm trying to manipulate some XML-based files based on XPATH. using DOM. But I have a issue in working with complex XPath.

Basically what i need is change the person name where email is xyz@gmail.com
where XPath be //person[email='xyz@gmail.com']/name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<details>
   <person>
      <name>batman</name>
      <email>abc@yahoo.com</email>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>spiderman</name>
      <email>xyz@gmail.com</email>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>tintin</name>
      <email>pqr@gmail.com</email>
   </person>
</details>
```

My current implementation as below

```
     Node nodeXpath = (Node) xPath.evaluate(<<xpath>>,document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE);
     Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
     Node tatgetNode = document.importNode(nodeXpath, true);
     element.getElementsByTagName(tatgetNode.getNodeName()).item(0).setTextContent("BatMan");
```

Issue is if I find element using tagName it does return NodeList with all nodes which matches with "name".

Can someone please point me how I can modify XML content based on XPath using DOM.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text contents of the node returned by `evaluate()` directly:

```
Node nodeXpath = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//person[email='xyz@gmail.com']/name",document, XPathConstants.NODE);
nodeXpath.setTextContent("BatMan");
```

Another way is to use XSLT:

```
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource("batmanTransform.xsl"));
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
StreamResult target = new StreamResult(System.out);
t.transform(new DOMSource(document), target);
```

and in batmanTransform.xsl, put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="//person[email='xyz@gmail.com']/name">
        <name>BatMan</name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```